Cognitive Sciences self-evaluation: let's get critical!
You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!
Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?
Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.
Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Software for online psychological experiments that don't require users to download anything
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

this was asked by a colleague of mine, and the answers have had an effect on how a real psychology experiment is being run. This is definitely the sort of tools questions we should aspire to answer. I just wish I could have convinced the OP to have a little more follow through on the question.

Is it possible to quantify cognitive bias?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

This is an interesting question; the term "cognitive bias" is fairly general which means that the question can be answered in many different ways.

How to analyze reaction times and accuracy together?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

+1 A good technical question. It could have been answered at stats.SE, but I think our community did a good job of providing a strong and useful answer.

This is actually a question that cannot be answered (i.e., this question is not reasonable answered yet). However, I like how various suggestions/answers are compiled in this question. I would like it more if none of it would have been accepted and the question could have been tagged "discussion" instead.

@H.Muster certainly no discussion tags. An answer with multiple solutions, all of which having some separate value is fine, a "discussion" where there's never more value in any one argument is not a question (unless it's on Meta)

Yes, I know that this is not the way SE works.

A lot of good, quality answers (not just "me too"s).

What are the major structures of the medial temporal lobe?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

This post is underrated! It's a great technical question with an awesome answer.

I think this ends up being a "list" question with a polished exterior.  Still, the answer is excellent.

I am also a little bit worried about it being a general reference question, but the obvious google search did not return a better result than the answer on our site.

Is The magical number 7 still valid?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

I think this is a very pop-psychology question (-1), it is likely to attract non-expert readers, but probably not as interesting for experts; it could have easily been asked at skeptics.SE. The top answer is very nice though (+1) and provides the sort of "known to practitioners but never officially written down" knowledge that research based SEs are great for.

Actually the "magical number 7" has received some attention in neuroscience lately, as there are some (testable) theories that explain this effect by theta-gamma phase amplitude coupling. I know of studies testing this theory that are currently carried out.

Effect of words highlighting on reading comprehension
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Fine question and good answer. I think it would be of interest to other SE users.

Are there any standard tests to measure psychopathy?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Great answer, question wasn't worded well so I've edited it. It's a straightforward simple question

Poor question (-1) but good answer (+1). The OP should have done some homework and searching before asking the question.

Is there a term for trying to remember a word, but only remembering its first letter?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

The question isn't worded well for discoverability but I guess that's to be expected for "I don't know what the word for this is"?

-1 this question could have just as easily been answered on English.SE.

What is the term for "What has been seen cannot be unseen" in cognitive sciences?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

I voted this question up to encourage a new user, but it's somewhat vague and not particularly well worded. Hopefully it drew him into the site but it doesn't really represent what I think this site can become. Actually it looks like it failed completely as it's that user's only question. -1.

Had a lot of potential, but it's hard to ask an OP for a complete overhaul, and even less likely that they will go along with it.

@ChuckSherrington it's really not...just ask (I've gotten impressive results) and if they're not in favor of editing/don't know how but the community is, we can edit.

How much information on the "Identical Strangers" experiment was actually released?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

this seems more like a trivia question, than one about the actual science. Even though we allow questions about how science is carried out (in our on-topic fields) this does not seem like a question an actual researcher would have.

Could have been better researched, but also could have been reformulated.  Not the worst I've seen.
